# Unable to view ftp externally

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-virtual-machine

I've been trying to setup an ftp on a Azure VM for some time now and not able to get it to work externally.
I can view the ftp locally but that's as far as I have got.

This is what I have currently in a nutshell

**Windows Server 2012 Azure VM**

- Ftp site on IIS
- The IP address is unassigned on port 21
- Host name is blank
- Administrator and a user under FTP Authorzation rules with read, write permission
- Have a ftp folder on the root c: drive
- Given security rights to the user for read, write permission on folder level.

**Azure Portal**

- Created inbound security rule for port 21 and port 80
- Created public ip address for my website and ftp

**Firewall on VM**

- Allow ftp server to communicate through windows firewall server both private and public
- Inbound Rule: FTP Server, Local port 21
- Inbound Rule: FTP Server Passive, Local Portal 1024-65535
- Inbound Rule: FTP Server Secure, Local Port 990
- Outbound Rule: FTP Server, Local Portal 20
- Outbound Rule: FTP Server Secure, Local Portal 989

I can view my website via the external IP address but not the ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at setting up passive FTP on Azure.  By default you are going to be using Passive FTP unless you specify stateful FTP.  Passive FTP requires port 21 and then a range of ports specified for the communication to be successful.  This is because port 21 is used for the initial connection, then the client/server negotiates a random port for the actual file transfer.  Looks like you are just missing the port range.

Comment: So the Data Channel Port Range on IIS FTP Firewall Support was 7000-7014

- I entered the external IP address on FTP Firewall Support 
- Then added the same inbound port range 7000-7014 on Azure and that resolved my issue.

Thank you so much, you were spot on.